# What is the correct way to configure a Linux installation's partition system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, filesystems, mount

*What is the correct way to configure a hard drive for a Linux installation and what do the various mount point options do EXACTLY?*

---

Can someone please explain to me how the mount point thing works? I Understand that in a single partition setup the one partition must be set as the `/`... But what about a configuration where I want more than one partition? Will setting another partition's mount point to `/home` cause the `/home` directory to be completely moved to that partition thus no longer residing in the `/` directory? Or will the `/home` directory still be accessible from the root directory?

This all stems from my attempt at installing Ubuntu (as I type)... my goal was to have Ubuntu installed to a 100GB root, 5GB swap, and the rest as an empty personal directory. I set my partitions like so and received an error message (that I could apparently ignore) saying:

```
"No mount point is assigned for the ext4 file system in partition #6 of scsi1 (0,0,0)(sda)
If you do not go back in the partitioning menu and assign a mount point from there this partition will not be used at all."
```

Can someone help me out here? I could just go on with my thing, but I would prefer to not have to reinstall when I found out I did it wrong.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

EDIT: From what I am reading it sounds like the mount point of a directory effectively assigns all reading and writing with that directory to be done on the corresponding partition that you specify. i.e.: the partition mounted as "
/home" would contain nothing but the `/home` directory and would be referenced by the `/` directory. thus no files from the `/home` directory would actually exist in the partition mounted as `/`... am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've been reading is correct.

When you partition your linux hard drive with a separate /home, that will mount your home partition at /home.  This does mean that none of the /home files are stored in / but there is a link, you could say, that connects your /home and your /.

IF you want to partition manually Ubuntu does have some recommendations:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/apcs03.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated guide I found. http://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-14-04-installation-guide/

At a bare minimum, you need the root partition, and then the swap partition.